# Can I use gamelift with node.js servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know it may sound as a stupid question but I am new to all this backend stuff, so take it into account pls.

So, gamelift gives you a fleet of Amazon Linux (or Windows) servers where you can put your game and on top of that a lot of fancy features for gamedev. So if it is a simple Linux can I put there my node.js application? And if not then can I at least use some of the Gamelift functionality (SDK which is [available in javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift/faq/?nc1=h_ls)) while having my servers on ECS for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not a JS user, but come across this question.

It seems that Amazon has released GameLift SDK for Node.js: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js
You can use below command to install:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying out different solutions. But you can use node.js to create game server on Gamelift.
There are 2 options:

1. [Realtime server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/realtime-plan.html) - basically already setup environment to start a game server using node
2. [Custom server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/gamelift-integration.html) - Amazon supports only a couple of languages with their server SDK and js isn't one of them. Fortunately the user [dplusic](https://github.com/dplusic/GameLift-Nodejs-ServerSDK) at Github rewrote C# SDK in js, you should be able to use it to run a custom server using node.js